# SageMaker Estimator fit job never ends

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have the following code

```
estimator = Estimator(                                                     
    image_uri=ecr_image,                                                   
    role=role,                                                             
    instance_count=1,                                                      
    instance_type=instance_type,                                           
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters                                        
)                                                                          

estimator.fit({"training": "s3://" + sess.default_bucket() + "/" + prefix})
```

which seems to run smoothly until it is stuck at:

```
Finished Training
2020-12-02 15:00:45,352 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Reporting training SUCCESS
```

and I see InProgress job in AWS SageMaker console. How can I fix this?

I use `763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference-eia:1.3.1-cpu-py36-ubuntu16.04` Docker image with `pip install sagemaker-training` added.

Comment: Hi, is there anything relevant in Cloudwatch ?

Comment: No, nothing in my code checks Cloudwatch. Why?

Comment: I mean .. is there any error in the cloudwatch logs generated by the training job ?

Comment: No, no error output. I think the issue is in line 27 of https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/multi_model_bring_your_own/container/dockerd-entrypoint.py. I am not sure why docker container is prevented from exit.

Comment: I think you are right, since you are using a container that is for inference (and you linked the entrypoint), which never exit because it's made to create an endpoint..